# VS2013 has_nothrow_constructor with protected constructor

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, visual-studio-2013, stl

With VS2013, has_nothrow_constructor and has_nothrow_default_constructor follow the standard more closely. It now states that:

[> N3797 20.10.4.3 [meta.unary.prop] says that is_nothrow_default_constructible is equivalent to is_nothrow_constructible. Then it says that is_nothrow_constructible requires is_constructible to be true (and additionally the construction must be "known not to throw any exceptions"). Finally, /6 defines is_constructible in terms of "T t(create()...);" being well-formed, and says that "Access checking is performed as if in a context unrelated to T and any of the Args."](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/804431/regression-for-has-nothrow-default-constructor-when-throw-is-specified-for-default-consructor)

This becomes a bit of a problem when working with a template where I want to basically test the throw capability of a baseclass constructor where it may be protected. For example:

```
namespace
{
    class CMyBase
    {
    protected:
        CMyBase() throw(){};
    };

    template < typename BlockCopyableClass >
    class TestBlockCopyableBase : public BlockCopyableClass
    {
    protected:
        TestBlockCopyableBase() throw(){}
        ~TestBlockCopyableBase() throw(){}
    private:
        static_assert((std::has_nothrow_constructor< BlockCopyableClass >::value), "BlockCopyableBase classes must have nothrow c-tors");
        static_assert((std::has_nothrow_default_constructor< BlockCopyableClass >::value), "BlockCopyableBase classes must have no throw default c-tors");
    };

    class MyBlockCopyable : public TestBlockCopyableBase< CMyBase >
    {
    };
}
```

This would work on VS2012/VS2010 but with VS2013 it returns false. Is there a check that doesn't take constructor visibility into the equation?

**Additional Comments:** There are TONS of `CMyBase` type classes so modifications to those will be very time consuming (across multiple teams) and the code will still need to compile on VS2010.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would have suggested checking `noexcept(BlockCopyableClass())`, but VS2013 doesn't support it :/

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a check that doesn't take constructor visibility into the equation?

No, there is not.
The fact that it worked in VS2010/2012 was probably a bug.

`has_nothrow_constructor` and `has_nothrow_default_constructor` are relics from tr1 (circa 2006). The feature that has was standardized was `is_nothrow_constructible` and `is_nothrow_default_constructible`. You should probably use those - but they won't give you different answers; they'll just make your code more portable.

Neither of these deal with non-public constructors. Because the constructors are inaccessible, the checks return false. The type is not default constructible `std::is_default_constructible< BlockCopyableClass>::value` is `false`, therefore it cannot be nothrow default constructible.